# How do I search for a question I posted?

Tags: support, search

I asked about something on U&L some time ago.  How do I search for my own question, based on a word in the subject line?  For the search - I only want results with questions from me.  Can that be done, if so how?

Comment: Since this is not a discussion forum, but a questions and answers site, I changed "posts started by me" to "questions from me" in the text.  If this misrepresents what you intended with your Meta question, then please clarify it.

Answer (score 5):

It's not too bad, once you know where to look!  The way I usually do it is to:

1. go to the profile, e.g. [mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/117549/jeff-schaller) or [yours ("current" magic link)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/current)
2. the search box near the top will have inserted text, such as `user:117549`. Add to that: `is:q title:word-to-search-for`, such as `is:q title:systemd`; the resulting search will be limited to questions that you asked that have the given word in the title.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/searching for more search operators. Hat tip to [Glorfindel's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327976/307535) for the /current link.

Kusalananda points out a shorter version:

1. In the search box, enter: `user:me is:q title:word-to-search-for`
2. There is no step 2! :)

Comment: `user:me` also works, no need to find the right user ID number.